# Euler's way of approximating roots of polynomials

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I am currently stuck with the understanding of this method.

```
a) Obtain the expansion of the indicated function in powers of x through the x^60 term.
b) Let r = (coefficient of x^59)/(coefficient of x^60)
c) evaluate the numerical value in decimals of the denominator of the indicated function for x=r

Ex: we are given a function 1/(1 - x - x^2)
obtain the expansion f the indicated function in powers of x through the x^60 term
1+x+......+1548008755920*x^59 + 2504730781961*x^60

r = (coefficient of x^59)/(coefficient of x^60)
r = 1548008755920/2504730781961

Obtain the denominator of f[x]
denominator = (1 - x - x^2)

substitute x=r into the denominator (1 - x - x^2)
result is 1.5939617*10^(-25)
The above result is approximately 0.
```

But when we use the algorithm to find a result for f[x] = 1/(1 - 2 x + 4 x^2 - 3 x^3)
obtain the expansion f the indicated function in powers of x through the x^60 term
1+x+......+79346514001800*x^59 + 198032082910801*x^60

```
r = (coefficient of x^59)/(coefficient of x^60)
r = 79346514001800/198032082910801

Obtain the denominator of f[x]
denominator = (1 - 2 x + 4 x^2 - 3 x^3)

substitute x=r into the denominator (1 - 2 x + 4 x^2 - 3 x^3)
result is 0.647838
```

Why does the second example deviate away from being approximated to 0.
We are asked to formulate theory as to why why this procedure will produce good approximations of roots of the denominators in some cases but is bound to fail in others.

We are given the following tips to guide us
(1) An expansion in powers of x converges on an interval determined by the complex singularity closest to zero.
(2) The Ratio Test also gives information on convergence.

But i'm absolutely stumped with all of this. Any help will be immense.

Answer (score 1):

Euler's Method seeks the root with the smallest absolute value, but it works only when such a root is unique.  In your second equation there is no unique smallest root; there is instead a pair of complex conjugates whose common absolute value ($1/\sqrt3$) is smaller than that of the remaining real root ($1$).  Faced with this situation Euler's Method, stuck with real numbers, is as unfortunately lost in indecision as [Buridan's ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass).

If you reverse the order of the coefficients, making $1$ the unique root with smallest absolute value, then Euler's Method will work perfectly well.

Comment: But does it explain why the procedure produces good approximations of denominators on some like (1 - x - x^2) but fails in (1 - 2 x + 4 x^2 - 3 x^3). Doesn't (1 - 2 x + 4 x^2 - 3 x^3) have a root at x=1?

Comment: But that is not the absolutely smallest root in the second case.  That is where we fall.